# What was integration by parts inspired by?

Tags: calculus

I have always wanted to ask this question about integration by parts. Was it actually inspired by the product rule? I always use the product rule to memorize the by parts formula. Let $u$ and $v$ be 2 functions of $x$. The original by-parts function is

$$
\int u\,dv = uv - \int v\,du
$$
If you start from product rule,

$$
\frac{d}{dx} uv = u\,dv\,dx  + v\,du\,dx\\
\int \frac{d}{dx} uv \,dx = \int u\,dv\,dx  + \int v\,du\,dx
$$

Finally, by rearrangement
$$
\int \frac{d}{dx} uv \,dx - \int v\,du\,dx = \int u\,dv\,dx \\
 \int u\,dv\,dx = \int \frac{d}{dx} uv \,dx - \int v\,du\,dx
$$

I think it was a stroke of genius by discovering this. But perhaps somebody could enlighten me.

Comment: You're right, that's just the integration of the product rule. I was not here when it was discovered. But surely derivatives and the product rule where known before integrals.

Comment: thank you @julien! was there any trace in mathematics history that this was discovered?

Comment: You mix thing up when you have $\frac{d}{dx}uv = udv +vdu$. It should be either $d(uv)$ on the left or $u\frac{dv}{dx}+v\frac{du}{dx}$ on the right.

Comment: I really don't know. Maybe it was inspired by the [summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) we do with series...

Comment: Note, related to my comment above, $\int u\,dv\,dx$ doesn't mean anything in this context. What you mean here can be written either as:$$\int u\frac{dv}{dx}\,dx$$ or $$\int u\,dv$$

Comment: Hello Thomas Andrews, I have made the relevant changes. Apologies for the inconsistency of the representations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In his book "The Calculus Gallery: Masterpieces from Newton to Lebesgue", William Dunham discusses the (*very* roundabout) way in which Leibnitz deduced a formula equivalent to integration by parts by considering figures.